# Ionic / Angular ng-click for select input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a select input that is placed over a musical time signature using CSS but with a very low opacity so its not visible.

When clicking the time signature the user actually clicks the select input bring up the options.

However, I need a way to know when a user has clicked a select input so that I can add a class to the time signature.

This question is not about the options in a select, I already have that working fine with ng-change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use CSS?

```
input:focus {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Although the element I need to target is not the select input. I can however do input:focus ~ .element